# How to open WhatsApp using an Intent in your Android App

Tags: android, android-intent, comments, onclicklistener, whatsapp

I want an Intent to take control you directly to WhatsApp. So the moment the user clicks on the button, the Intent is supposed to take you to WhatsApp.
This is the code I wrote after following a few guide lines but it doesn't work

```
buttonWhatsapp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Performs action on click
            Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
            sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text to send.");
            sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
            sendIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, ""));
            startActivity(sendIntent);
            //opens the portfolio details class
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 97):

Using the 2018 api:

```
String url = "https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone="+number;
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: It worked for me. Want to mention that I needed to send the number in the format of +00 0000000000

Comment: If WhatsApp is not installed on the device, it will open a web browser to handle this. Nice!

Comment: I've opened this URL with my number in my mobile browser. I've my own chat now, which will make non IT people go wow 

Comment: This is better, because do not need the Whatsapp Installed on App

Comment: to add `message` you have to use `"https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=$phoneNumber"+"&text=" + URLEncoder.encode(message, "UTF-8")`

Comment: how I can make it not open browser when the app is not installed ?

Comment: @sattar check if whatsapp is installed, before passing the intent to the OS

Answer (score 42):

> This code working for me

```
String contact = "+00 9876543210"; // use country code with your phone number
    String url = "https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=" + contact;
    try {
         PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
         pm.getPackageInfo("com.whatsapp", PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
         Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
         i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
         startActivity(i);                            
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.activity, "Whatsapp app not installed in your phone", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: on Android 11 you also need to add `<queries> <package android:name="com.whatsapp" /> </queries>` on manifest

Answer (score 18):

**This works perfectly 2021**

Expansion of short forms:

numero = number phone

mensaje= message to send

```
private void openWhatsApp(String numero,String mensaje){

    try{
        PackageManager packageManager = getActivity().getPackageManager();
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        String url = "https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone="+ numero +"&text=" + URLEncoder.encode(mensaje, "UTF-8");
        i.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
        i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
        if (i.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null) {
            startActivity(i);
        }else {
            KToast.errorToast(getActivity(), getString(R.string.no_whatsapp), Gravity.BOTTOM, KToast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        Log.e("ERROR WHATSAPP",e.toString());
        KToast.errorToast(getActivity(), getString(R.string.no_whatsapp), Gravity.BOTTOM, KToast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    }

}
```

Hope, This Helps!

Answer (score 15):

***Feb 2024***
 Just a little more peachy answer: 
Don't forget to add the country code before the number, I mean **use the full phone number in international format**, without leading zeros, brackets, or dashes. (+1...)

```
public static void setClickToChat(View v,String toNumber){
    String url = "https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=" + toNumber;
    try {
        PackageManager pm = v.getContext().getPackageManager();
        pm.getPackageInfo("com.whatsapp", PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
        v.getContext().startActivity(i);
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        v.getContext().startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
    }
}
```

**Kotlin** View extension function :

```
fun View.openWhatsAppChat(toNumber: String) {
   val url = "https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=$toNumber"
   try {
       context.packageManager.getPackageInfo("com.whatsapp", PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES)
       context.startActivity(Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).apply { data = Uri.parse(url) })
   } catch (e: PackageManager.NameNotFoundException) {
       context.startActivity(Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)))}}
```

**Jetpack Compose** :

```
val toNumber = "+123456789"
val msg = "Hello from Stackoverflow!"
val url = "https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=$toNumber"
val context = LocalContext.current
val packageManager = LocalContext.current.packageManager
val intent: Intent = try {
    Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND).apply {
        type = "text/plain"
        putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, msg)
        putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER, toNumber)
        val info = packageManager.getPackageInfo("com.whatsapp", PackageManager.GET_META_DATA)
        `package` = "com.whatsapp"
    }
} catch (e: PackageManager.NameNotFoundException) {
    Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url))
}

Button(
    onClick = {
        context.startActivity(intent)
    }
) { Text(text = "Open WhatsApp",) }
```

Comment: We need to append +91 (country code) and then number to make it work. e.g +919876543210 (dummy number)

Comment: I have tried it, but just opening send to screen of whatsapp

Comment: @LalitJadav Have you entered the recipient's number correctly (with country code)?

Comment: yes, but not worked for audio file

Comment: What if there's no country code with the number, how would we get whatsapp to start the chat?

Comment: @hemaezzat No worries, country code or not, just use the full phone number in international format (without leading zeros, brackets, or dashes) to start a WhatsApp chat

Answer (score 7):

The easiest way i know is by calling the following method (Use the String variable (message) to input the text you want to send via WhatAapp):

```
private void sendWhatsapp(String message){
    Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
    sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);
    sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
    sendIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
    if (sendIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivity(sendIntent);
    }
}
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: how you can add phone number here ?

Answer (score 7):

```
btnWhatsapp.setOnClickListener ( new View.OnClickListener () {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startSupportChat ();
            }
        } );

private void startSupportChat() {

        try {
            String headerReceiver = "";// Replace with your message.
            String bodyMessageFormal = "";// Replace with your message.
            String whatsappContain = headerReceiver + bodyMessageFormal;
            String trimToNumner = "+910000000000"; //10 digit number
            Intent intent = new Intent ( Intent.ACTION_VIEW );
            intent.setData ( Uri.parse ( "https://wa.me/" + trimToNumner + "/?text=" + "" ) );
            startActivity ( intent );
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace ();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 4):

This is working method. To call this method call like

```
call like this - openWhatsApp(919876543210)

 private void openWhatsApp(String smsNumber) {
    Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Hi, This is " + PreferenceManager.get(this, Constants.USERNAME));
    sendIntent.putExtra("jid", smsNumber + "@s.whatsapp.net"); //phone number without "+" prefix
    sendIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
    if (sendIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) == null) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Error/n", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }
    startActivity(sendIntent);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In Kotlin, this is how you would do it.

Open Specific user WhatsApp Number and send a typed message

```
startActivity(
        Intent(
            Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
            Uri.parse(
                "https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=Phone Number&text=Message to send"
            )
        )
    )
```

Answer (score 3):

Hey this snippet is from the official whatsapp site

https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/android/28000012

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text to send.");
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
sendIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
startActivity(sendIntent);
```

Comment: yep, I know that and thats what I wrote first but it doesn't work

Comment: It's working, but then you have to manually, select target receiver.

Answer (score 2):

```
 PackageManager pm = getActivity().getPackageManager();

    try
    {
        // Raise exception if whatsapp doesn't exist
        PackageInfo info = pm.getPackageInfo("com.whatsapp", PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);

        Intent waIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        waIntent.setType("text/plain");
        waIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
        waIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "YOUR TEXT");
        startActivity(waIntent);
    }
    catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e)
    {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.activity, "Please install whatsapp app", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
    }
```

Comment: yea I will try it now

Comment: @  Ali Gürelli It says that it cannot resolve the symbol activity

Comment: It now has an error that it cannot resolve the method getActivity()

Answer (score 2):

I am showing you how to share text and image both here,
For sharing text you can use these code ,

```
private void shareTextUrl() {
    Intent share = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    share.setType("text/plain");
    share.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);

    // Add data to the intent, the receiving app will decide
    // what to do with it.
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Title Of The Post");
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "http://www.codeofaninja.com");

    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share link!"));
}
```

Now if you want to share image then you can use  these code ,

```
private void shareImage() {
    Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

    // If you want to share a png image only, you can do:
    // setType("image/png"); OR for jpeg: setType("image/jpeg");
    share.setType("image/*");

    // Make sure you put example png image named myImage.png in your
    // directory
    String imagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + "/myImage.png";

    File imageFileToShare = new File(imagePath);

    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(imageFileToShare);
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);

    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Image!"));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

this solution work for me :)

```
 val url = "https://wa.me/WHATSAPP_NUMBER"
        val i = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
        i.data = Uri.parse(url)
        startActivity(i)
```

Answer (score 2):

**My code is a little bit the same but I handled this in a very effective way that runs in all devices up to API 30+ you can try this**

```
//to open whats app app
    fun openApp(activity: Activity,packageName:String) {

        if (isAppInstalled(activity, packageName))
            activity.startActivity(activity.packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName))
        else
            Toast.makeText(activity, "App not installed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }

    fun isAppInstalled(activity: Activity, packageName: String?): Boolean {
        val pm = activity.packageManager
        try {
            pm.getPackageInfo(packageName!!, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES)
            return true
        } catch (e: PackageManager.NameNotFoundException) {
            Log.e("isAppInstalled", "error :${e.message}")
        }
        return false
    }
```

In AndroidManifest.xml outside of the application scope just add this query

```
<manifest>

/*user permissions here whatever you want according to your need*/

    <queries>
             <package android:name="com.whatsapp"/>
             <package android:name="com.whatsapp.w4b"/>
             <package android:name="com.gbwhatsapp"/>
        </queries>
<application> /*here you have registered your activities*/ </application>
</manifest>
```

I hope this will help anyone you find helpful vote me up. Remember me in your prayer.

Answer (score 1):

this work for this days ago

```
 private void openWhatsApp(String number) {
    try {
        number = number.replace(" ", "").replace("+", "");

        Intent sendIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
        sendIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.whatsapp","com.whatsapp.Conversation"));
        sendIntent.putExtra("jid", PhoneNumberUtils.stripSeparators(number)+"@s.whatsapp.net");
       // getApplication().startActivity(sendIntent);

        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Compartir en")
                .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));

    } catch(Exception e) {
        Log.e("WS", "ERROR_OPEN_MESSANGER"+e.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: what is jid for?

Answer (score 1):

For ***`Business Whatsapp and normal Whatsapp`***:

To handle both **business whatsapp** and **normal whatsapp**, the url scheme intent needs to be used, since the normal method of using package "com.whatsapp" only works for normal whatsapp.

Here's the code sample to handle both normal and **business whatsapp** :

```
try {
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        i.setData(Uri.parse("whatsapp://send?text=The text message goes here");
        context.startActivity(i);
    } catch (Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(context, "Whatsapp not installed!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

This will open a chooser if both whatsapp are installed and if only either one of them is installed that particular version will be launched.

Answer (score 1):

> This code worked for me.

```
public void openWhatsapp(View view) {
    String message = mMessOpenWhatEdit.getText().toString();     // take message from the user

    // create an Intent to send data to the whatsapp
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);    // setting action

    // setting data url, if we not catch the exception then it shows an error
    try {
        String url = "https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=+91 0000000000" + "&text=" + URLEncoder.encode(message, "UTF-8");
        intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    catch(UnsupportedEncodingException e){
        Log.d("notSupport", "thrown by encoder");
    }
}
```

Comment: openWhatsapp is a onclick method(I mean it is called after clicking button in ui)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to launch/open WhatsApp application or WhatsApp Business application in android on button click then follow these code.

**Launch WhatsApp Business application:**

```
public void launchWhatsAppBusinessApp(View v)
{ 
   PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
   try
   {
      
       Intent intent = this.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.whatsapp.w4b");
       startActivity(intent);
       }
catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e)
       {
           Toast.makeText(this, "Please install WA Business App", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
catch(NullPointerException exception){}
   }
```

**Launch WhatsApp application:**

```
public void openWhatsApp(View v)
{
    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    try
    {
        
        Intent intent = this.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.whatsapp");
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please install WhatsApp App", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    catch(NullPointerException exception){}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code snipped for kotin.

```
try {
                val sendIntent = Intent().apply {
                    action = Intent.ACTION_SEND
                    putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Hello Swapz")
                    putExtra("jid", "${data.phone}@s.whatsapp.net")
                    type = "text/plain"
                    setPackage("com.whatsapp")
                }
                startActivity(sendIntent)
            }catch (e: Exception){
                e.printStackTrace()
               val appPackageName = "com.whatsapp"
                try {
                    startActivity(Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=$appPackageName")))
                } catch (e :android.content.ActivityNotFoundException) {
                    startActivity(Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=$appPackageName")))
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
tvWhatsapp.setOnClickListener(v -> {

   Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
   intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=+......."));
   startActivity(intent);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

only wants to open whatsApp in kotlin in activity

`val packagename = "com.whatsapp" val intent = packagemanager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("packagename")  intent?. let{startActivity(it)}`

change only packages for others application
for whatsapp business

`packagename ="com.whatsapp.w4b"`

in Fragment use
`requiredActivity(). packagemanager` 
instead of
 `packagemanager`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).