# How to open Whatsapp on Android using Linking.canOpenUrl

Tags: android, react-native

I want to open whatsapp on react native using a buttton press. But I want to use Linking.canOpenUrl?
How do I do that?

I tried add intent to androidManifest.xml file in react native like

```
  <queries>
   <intent>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="whatsapp" />
</intent>
</queries>
```

Comment: This should get you on the right track. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38422300/how-to-open-whatsapp-using-an-intent-in-your-android-app

Comment: Also, to get more specific answers, have a look at [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

Add intent to androidManifest.xml file

```
   <queries>Share.Social.WHATSAPP
      <!-- Specific apps you share to -->
      <package android:name="com.whatsapp" />
      <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
      </intent>
    </queries>
```

Sample example for sharing file or text to the WHATSAPP

> npm i react-native-share

```
 import Share from 'react-native-share';

 let options = {
        title: "APP",
        message: "",
        url: "Url is here",
        subject: "",
        social: Share.Social.WHATSAPP,
        forceDialog: true,
    }
    Share.shareSingle(options)
        .then((response) => {
             // handle response here
        }).catch((error) => {
            // handle error here
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

Add intent to androidManifest.xml file

```
<queries>    
  <package android:name="com.whatsapp" />       
  <intent>         
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />         
  <data android:scheme="whatsapp" />        
  </intent>     
</queries>
```

And Then Work for Linking.canOpenURL